# How to parse CCD/CDA document in Apache/Adobe flex?

Tags: apache, actionscript-3, flex4, mxmlc, adobe-flash-cs3

How to parse CCD/CDA document in adobe flex? 
Is there any simple solution/Third party library to parse and show all the human readable part present in XML rather than iterating over each node and parsing it individually?

Now i am parsing it by iterating over each node and parsing meaning full data and showing it in UI.But iam not able to parse all the data for some XML document,since some of the XML have multiple children inside parent but some not,so need to check with all the scenario and need to do code accordingly? this creates lots of problem for me and issue in parser is not able fix at a time

Comment: I don't mean to discourage you, but you're asking for something too specific. I googled a bit and I think your best shot is either **Google > ccd/cda javascript** as it is very close to AS3, or their own open-source SDK: https://hl7sdk.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for this guide,It may be a grate help for me. I think i need to dig inside those Javasctipt code and convert it to AS3 code. Hope i am bit close to the solution